# Robust 3 way ANOVA in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova, statistics-bootstrap, robust

I'm trying to conduct a 3 way Anova in R, using the WRS2 package.
My data is heteroskedastic so i need to do a robust version e.g. trimmed means.
I have my data arranged in long form (csv with 4 columns - 3 factors and 1 numeral). My input looks like this:

```
t3way(happiness ~ money*job*relationship, data = Dataset)
```

I get the following error: "Incomplete design! It needs to be full factorial!"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably one of your variables is not factorial. Provide an example of the data.

Comment: i tried a standard aov with the same input and it computes.

Data looks like this:
`happiness: continuous values from 0 to 3
money: 8 categories 1 to 8
job: 5 categories
relationship 4 categories: 0,1,2,3`

Comment: a small sample can be found here: [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiejnoNjAUvPhVgdwr9-wXxhecqY)

Comment: ok i guess not every factor combination is avaliable in my data. so what are my options for a robust 3 way anova?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem by re-factoring the variable with  empty levels. 
Dataset$myvar <- factor(Dataset$myvar)
Thus only the levels having data remain. Then the t3way worked fine.